# WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used

Tags: spring-boot, undertow

In my SpringBoot application logs I see the following WARNs:

```
UT026009: XNIO worker was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default worker will be used
UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
```

From a Google search it seems they could be related to Undertow suggesting for an improvement which seems to be impossible to be implemented.

Does anyone have any further clarifications on these, and maybe a suggestion on how to make the logs disappear since the application runs just fine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a heads up for configuration of buff pool and does not effect in using.

As suggested from https://blog.csdn.net/weixin_39841589/article/details/90582354,

```java
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {
 
    @Override
    public void customize(UndertowServletWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addDeploymentInfoCustomizers(deploymentInfo -> {
            WebSocketDeploymentInfo webSocketDeploymentInfo = new WebSocketDeploymentInfo();
            webSocketDeploymentInfo.setBuffers(new DefaultByteBufferPool(false, 1024));
            deploymentInfo.addServletContextAttribute("io.undertow.websockets.jsr.WebSocketDeploymentInfo", webSocketDeploymentInfo);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a pity that you have to add this boilerplate just to get rid of an irrelevant warning.

Comment: Almost 2 years later it's still a problem.

Comment: Thank you guy, I'm a WARN's allergic. This helps so much. ;)

I have changed a little detail, to meet my configs organization, so I get:

```
@Configuration
public class UndertowConfig implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<UndertowServletWebServerFactory> {  ... }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need web sockets, you can exclude them, which will make the message go away:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude web sockets -->
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Where does this code go?

Answer (score 2):

If not using WebSocket in Undertow on SpringBoot.

```
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow") {
    exclude group: "io.undertow", module: "undertow-websockets-jsr"
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where does this code go?